# Consecutive If Else Statements

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I putting two if else statements one after the other in my code. When I add the second one the code does not work at all. I am getting a syntax error that says expecting semicolon. Whats wrong?

Here is the working code with one if else.

```js
window.onload = function() {
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<img alt="image" src="images/image.png">';
div.style.visibility = "visible";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.zIndex = "3";
div.className = "div";
div.id = "div";
document.body.appendChild(div);
document.onmousemove=function(e){
  var x, y;
  var div = document.getElementById('div');
  if (e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;} else {x=event.clientX;y=event.clientY;};

  div.style.top=y+'px';
  div.style.left=x-90+'px';
  }};
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the one with two if else statements that does not work

```js
    window.onload = function() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<img alt="image" src="images/image.png">';
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.zIndex = "3";
    div.className = "div";
    div.id = "div";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    document.onmousemove=function(e){
      var x, y;
      var div = document.getElementById('div');
      if (e) {x=e.clientX; y=e.clientY;} else {x=event.clientX;y=event.clientY;};
      if (x = 0) {div.style.visibility=hidden;} else {div.style.visibility= visible;};
      div.style.top=y+'px';
      div.style.left=x-90+'px';
      }};
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `div.style.visibility: hidden` => `div.style.visibility = hidden` and etc

Comment: Try changing this line, if (x = 0) {div.style.visibility: hidden;} else {div.style.visibility: visible;}; to this,

if (x = 0) {div.style.visibility = hidden;} else {div.style.visibility = visible;};

Comment: Surely `if (x == 0)`? It's a comparison, not an assignment you want. Also, `div.style.visibility = "hidden";` - running the code as-is here spews errors without the quotes. PS: Don't fix bugs in your original code without commenting, as it makes the comments above look wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (x = 0) {div.style.visibility: hidden;} else {div.style.visibility: visible;};
```

This line does not mean what you think it means. You're assigning `0` to `x` instead of comparing `0` to `x`, and the colons are syntax errors. Also, there's an empty statement at the end of the line.

Comment: And there must be quotes around `hidden` and `visible`.

Comment: Well, `hidden` and `visible` could have been variables (: